# Luxon does not format (DD'MM yyyy) format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/) deprecated according to its documentation, So I used [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) in my react project. I need to format the date like **DD'MM yyyy**, Luxon does not accept this format while MomentJs successfully did it. If you guys find any way to handle this in Luxon please answer:

MomentJS

```
moment('06/24/2020').format('DD\'MM yyyy')  // output is = 24'06 2020
```

Luxon

```
console.warn(DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date("06/24/2020")).toFormat('dd\'MM yyyy')); // output is = 24MM yyyy
```

Answer (score 5):

Luxon [uses single quotes as an escape character](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#escaping), so it's currently not possible to insert a literal single quote. According to [Luxon GitHub issue #649 *Escaping single quote*](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/649), it seems like this is a known limitation.

Short of opening a PR yourself, you could work around it like this:

```js
DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date('06/24/2020')).toFormat('dd!MM yyyy')
    .replace('!', "'")
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the perfect answer. +1